# asp.net dropdown list selected value

Tags: asp.net

For first time when the page loads we are unable to retrieve selected drop down value which consists of page numbers in dropdown list.Here is my dropdown list

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlpagenubers" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
 onselectedindexchanged="ddlpagenubers_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
```

i did a custom paging in a datalist by placing a dropdown consisting of page number to navigate to particular pages

Comment: what is your actual requirement? not so clear in your question.

Comment: i edited my question please have a look at it

Comment: how can you get the selected value when page load for the first time? page should be load first for someone to select a value. Isnt'it?

Comment: @uma.n, you have edited your question but not properly given what you actually need?

Comment: when page loads it is  set to first index by default.and after clicking on it say i select page number "2" it is displaying the index which is set as default

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx

Comment: @kalyan have u seen the below comment? did u understand wat i am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{           
    var query = datasource();    // order by page id

    if(query != null)
    {
        ddlpagenubers.DataSource = query;
        ddlpagenubers.DataValueField = "ID";//page id
        ddlpagenubers.DataTextField = "Name";//page name
        ddlpagenubers.DataBind();                    
    }

    var value = ddlpagenubers.SelectedValue;

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    {
        DispalyPage(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not `Binding` the DropDownList when the page is postback, otherwise it will reset itself.

Comment: no i am not binding it when the page posts back.only for the first selection it is showing the default  value which is set.From second time all is going well